# Struts1 to Struts2 Migration action mapping issue

Tags: struts2

I am converting my struts1 project to struts2 using struts2-struts1 plugin ( pom.xml)
In pom.xml i have included dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-struts1-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.36</version>
</dependency>
```

In struts1 config file action mapping is of specific type

```
<action-mappings type="com.inetpsa.fwk.struts.config.FWKActionMapping">
```

In struts2 how can use this as i dont have any attribute "type"?

For more information : i am tryin to convert struts1 projecct to struts2 and i am using struts2-struts1-plugin  to convert so that its not nessary to changes your actions and form classes.

Now in struts-config.xml i am using intrerceptors

```
<package name="struts" extends="xxx-default" namespace="/">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="LoginForm" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor">
                <param name="className">com.xxxx.xxx.beans.forms.LoginForm</param>
                <param name="name">loginForm</param>
                <param name="scope">request</param>
            </interceptor>
```

In struts1

```
<action-mappings type="com.inetpsa.fwk.struts.config.FWKActionMapping">
```

this is  Fully qualified Java class to use when instantiating ActionMapping objects

Question is how can i do this type in Strust2

More example

in S1  i have one method

```
ActionForward doExecute(ActionMapping arg0, ActionForm arg1, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

ActionMapping -> ActionConfig[path=/newApvprStart,input=marque,name=MarqueForm,scope=request,type=com.inetpsa.oin.actions.OinStartAction,validate=false,cancellable=false
null
false
true
```

Request =-> com.inetpsa.jbn.servlet.wrappers.HttpServletRequestWrapper
Response -> org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade

in s2 when i use s2 s1 plugin

```
ActionMapping 
wrapper -> {ActionConfig newApvprStart (org.apache.struts2.s1.Struts1Action.execute()) - action - file:/C:/Users/E491181/workspace/poi-3/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/OinJipWeb/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:53:99}
null
null
null
false
```

request -> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsRequestWrapper
response -> org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade

Comment: Use what? What is it/what does it do? What functionality are you trying to duplicate? Without any details it's impossible to help.

Comment: I am trying to convert struts1 project to struts2, edited description for more information

Comment: That says nothing about what `FWKActionMapping` is, what it does, etc. All the S1 plugin does is (basically) marshall data in and out of S1 actions based on S2 functionality and JSP pages. Without knowing what you actually *need*, it's impossible to help. (All that said, personally I'd just rewrite things anyway, or run the apps in parallel.)

Comment: FwkActionMapping is my custom mapping class,

Comment: No kidding. I guessed that. How does this help me guess what functionality you'd need to duplicate in S2?

Comment: Need to duplicate n S2 the type of mapping for action mappings as u can see in <action-mapping we can define the type, but this is missing in S2?

Comment: ... You can't. Which is why I've been asking over and over what is the *functionality* you need to duplicate, but for whatever reason, you won't answer. So there's no way to help. Good luck!

Comment: Here is the documentation on how to map in action in S2.  It is completely different than S1.  https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html

Comment: Dave,    is there any alternative anywhere or in class wise? In class can we specify ActionMapper ?

Comment: Also while using struts2 plugin , do we need to change web.xml also? as my servelt in S1 is com.xx.xx.servlet.struts.XXXActionServlet and in S2 in web.xml i have now s2 dispatcher.. how can my S2 now go to com.xx.xx.servlet.struts.XXXActionServlet  by using S2-S2 plugin

Comment: @DaveNewton i have edited description for more info

Comment: You're missing what I'm saying: there is no equivalent. That's why I've been asking for the functionality you're trying to duplicate. You do not go to an S1 action servlet in S2. That's why I said to run the S1 and S2 apps in parallel: that way you don't have to migrate all your JSP pages at once, and your S1 functionality is duplicated precisely instead of just wrapping S1 actions in the S2 request processing flow. I don't know any other way to explain it.

Comment: i just want to migrate S1 to S2 without changing actions anf forms, in S1 the project has wrappers also as i said they have there custoim Action Mapping

Comment: And I'm saying if you want to do that you'll need to duplicate the functionality of your custom mapper in S2, and if you're doing anything "unusual" with your `ActionForm` classes you may have to tweak that as well. The bottom line is that S2 is a completely different framework than S1. You get essentially zero benefit in taking an S1 app and pretending it's an S2 app. What I'm saying is that you should run the two apps in parallel and convert over action by action, otherwise you're just wasting time and energy.

Comment: yes so stratergy would be to do one flow same as S1 in S2 and go step by step